# How to change all cells in a spreadsheet to just one font type and size?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice-calc

I just receive a spreadsheet that was converted from a PDF file. Due to the poor conversion, the cells contain a mixture of fonts and font sizes. For example in:

```
Future Insurance
```

The first character `F` is in Liberation Sans, size 10 but the rest of the characters are in Arial, size 5.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Select the entire spreadsheet and set the font to Liberation Sans,
  size 10. No visible change.
- Reduce the font size to 8 and then increase it back to 10. Only the
  first character in all cells react to the change in font size.
- Select one cell at a time and set the font size. Yes, this works, but is
  too tedious.
- Use the format painter. No, it doesn't work.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. select all cells
2. right click on mouse
3. click on `clear direct formatting`

Comment: Ah, yes, this does work. A side effect is that all other formatting is lost. But if no better option, then I am willing to take it.